# Как отследить клик по кнопке "назад" в браузере? JS

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно закрыть модальное окно при нажатии кнопки назад. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: В момент открытия сделать `history.pushState`, тогда при нажатии «Назад» сработает событие `popstate` на которое можно подписаться https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/History_API